# common java jar import into mule project

Tags: java, jar, dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to import a `common-math Java jar` into my mule project and just do basic functionality check of the java jar.

As per this blog https://mulesy.com/external-jar-class-in-dataweave/
I have added pom dependency and external package in mule-artifact.json.

mule-artifact.json

```
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.4.0",
  "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
    "id": "mule",
    "attributes": {
      "exportedPackages": [
        "org.apache.commons.math3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And now I have my data weave code has below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from java!org::apache::commons::math3::primes::Primes
output application/json
---
{
    a: Primes::isPrime(13)
}
```

It should return me either `true` or `false` as per java class.
But I'm getting error saying `Unable to resolve the reference of: Primes::isPrime`

What is missing, should I add the whole java package of `primes` in `src/main/java`?
Let me know how can I import an external java jar and perform the operations in Mulesoft defined in that jar..

Note: I have also installed this jar in my m2 repo

Answer (score 0):

You are using the package `prime` when the correct package for [Apache Commons Math3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html) is `primes`. The full package name is `org.apache.commons.math3.primes`.

I'm not sure it is really needed to declare the `exportedPackages` key in mule-artifact.json. In many cases is automatically configured at build. I would try to remove it. If it still needed use the full package.

Comment: im using the package as primes only - it was missed while copying here i guess - corrected the question

Comment: You haven't removed or corrected exportedPackages.